# Update the domain section of emails for certain users

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have many users that have the wrong domain for their email addresses and I want to mass update them all to only change the domain section of their email

The `@fake.com` part, same for all:

| users | email |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | user1@test.com |
| user2 | user2@test.com |
| user3 | user3@test.com |

I want to change the `@test.com` to `@fake.com` for example using the users names.

```
update userinfo 
set email = user1@fake.com
where users = 'user1'
```

I was able to update one user at a time but not sure what syntax to use for a list of user's names.

Comment: Why not use `REPLACE`?

Answer (score 3):

**Please** make sure you test this as a select **before** you use it. You need to be sure you're going to update the rows you intend to.

```
DECLARE @Emails TABLE (UserName NVARCHAR(20), UserEmail NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @Emails (UserName, UserEmail) VALUES
(N'user1', N'user1@test.com'), (N'user2', N'user2@test.com'), (N'user3', N'user3@test.com'); 

SELECT *, REPLACE(UserEmail,'@test.com','@fake.com')
  FROM @Emails
 WHERE UserEmail LIKE '%@test.com'

UPDATE e
   SET UserEmail = REPLACE(UserEmail,'@test.com','@fake.com')
  FROM @Emails e
 WHERE UserEmail LIKE '%@test.com';

SELECT *
  FROM @Emails;
```

Before:

| UserName | UserEmail | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | user1@test.com | user1@fake.com |
| user2 | user2@test.com | user2@fake.com |
| user3 | user3@test.com | user3@fake.com |

After:

| UserName | UserEmail |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | user1@fake.com |
| user2 | user2@fake.com |
| user3 | user3@fake.com |

So here we're using the `LIKE` operator to find just the rows that end with '@test.com' and then using a `REPLACE` to change '@test.com' with '@fake.com'.